# Mapping start date and end date according to revision dates map

Tags: java, time, jodatime

I have start_date: 2014-09-20 and end_date as 2014-09-23

I have a map which contains values like

```
key(revision)    Value

  109         2014-06-17
  110         2014-09-23
```

I need output to be in following format

```
Start date  End date    revision
2014-09-20  2014-09-22  109
2014-09-23  2014-09-23  110
```

I have following code but it fails if start date or end date provided are same.
RevisionInfo is bean class containing start_date(joda DateTime), end_date(joda DateTime) and revision(Integer)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    DateTime startDate = new DateTime("2014-09-20");
    DateTime endDate = new DateTime("2014-09-23");

   Map<Integer, DateTime> revisions = new HashMap<Integer, DateTime>();


    revisions.put(109, new DateTime("2014-06-17"));
    revisions.put(110, new DateTime("2014-09-23"));

    Map<Integer, DateTime> sortedRevisions = new TreeMap<Integer, DateTime>(revisions);

    DateTime nextRevisionStartDate  = startDate;
    Integer previousRevision  = null;

    List<RevisionInfo> revisionInfos = new ArrayList<RevisionInfo>();

    for (Integer revision : sortedRevisions.keySet()){

        if(sortedRevisions.get(revision).isAfter(endDate) ){
            break;
        }

        if(sortedRevisions.get(revision).isEqual(startDate) || sortedRevisions.get(revision).isAfter(startDate) ){

            if(revisionInfos.size() == 0)
            {
                if(previousRevision != null) {
                    revisionInfos.add(new RevisionInfo(startDate, sortedRevisions.get(revision).minusDays(1), previousRevision));
                    nextRevisionStartDate = sortedRevisions.get(revision);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                revisionInfos.add(new RevisionInfo(nextRevisionStartDate, sortedRevisions.get(revision).minusDays(1), previousRevision));
                nextRevisionStartDate = sortedRevisions.get(revision);
            }

        }

       previousRevision = revision;


    }


    revisionInfos.add(new RevisionInfo(nextRevisionStartDate, endDate, previousRevision));



    for (RevisionInfo revisionInfo : revisionInfos){

        System.out.println("Start Date :: "+ revisionInfo.getStartDate()+ ":: End date ::"+ revisionInfo.getEndDate()+": Revision:"+ revisionInfo.getRevision());
    }
}
```

Case which fails

Input dates provided are

```
Start_date   End_date
2014-09-23   2014-09-23
```

Output generated

```
Start_date   End_date    Revision
2014-09-23   2014-09-22   110
2014-09-23   2014-09-23   110
```

Expected Output is

```
Start_date   End_date    Revision
2014-09-23   2014-09-23   110
```

Comment: Can please be a bit more specific about what exactly is failing?  Are you getting an exception or just unexpected data?

Comment: I get wrong result like following
Start Date                End date    Revision
2014-09-23T00:00:00.000+05:30 2014-09-22T00:00:00.000+05:30 109
2014-09-23T00:00:00.000+05:30 2014-09-23T00:00:00.000+05:30 110

Comment: Also, unless I'm misinterpreting your code, it looks like you're comparing RevisionInfo classes to a joda DateTime class.  This will result in false unless you wrote a specific override for this.

Comment: No @JNYRanger I have a bean class revisionInfo which i have to populate.

Comment: It works for me. That is, it prints full date time and not just date because you chose to use `DateTime` rather than `Date`, but other than that I get the correct output as you wrote above.

Comment: @RealSkeptic yes it does works for most conditions but it fails if provided start_date and end_date are same as that of revison date.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a case that doesn't work and what you would expect it to show?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I have edited the question and provided the case which  fails for me. Thanks for your concern :)

Comment: Consider defining your intervals by the **Half-Open approach**, commonly used in date-time work. In Half-Open, the beginning is inclusive while the ending is exclusive. A week runs from a Monday to a Monday, going up to but not not excluding the second Monday. Sear h StackOverflow for more discussions and code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
    if(sortedRevisions.get(revision).isEqual(startDate) || sortedRevisions.get(revision).isAfter(startDate) ){
```

your condition should be only:

```
    if(sortedRevisions.get(revision).isAfter(startDate) ){
```

Explanation:

On each round, you look at the current revision, and decide whether to add the **previous revision** to the list.

If the current revision's date *is greater* than the start date, it means that the previous revision was still "in force" on the *actual* start date. For example, if the start date is `2014-10-05`, and the current revision starts on `2014-10-10`, it means that starting `2014-10-05` until `2014-10-09` the previous revision was still "in force".

But if the current revision starts on the actual start date (is equal), it means the previous version was **not** in force on that date. The current revision was already in force on the start date. Since at the moment you are deciding whether to add the **previous** revision, you reject it. And the current revision, which is good, will  be handled in the next round.